# The ebrake light in my car stays on when the ebrake is disengaged, should I be concerned?

Tags: ford, parking-brake

I have a 2002 Ford Taurus Station Wagon, and the ebrake light stays on when the ebrake is disengaged, should I be concerned?

I tried tramping down on the ebrake peddle really hard and then disengaging the ebrake, but when I pulled my hand back from the release, I noticed that my hand was covered in a mud-like substance.

Does this mean anything too?

P.S. It was raining at the time.

Answer (score 5):

Most cars use the same light to let you know there is a problem with the brakes, or the fluid level. While watching the light push down and release the emergency brake see if you see the light flicker. If you do it's not the emergency brake that is turning the light on, if not check the switch on the emergency brake usually on the e-brake handle or pedal.

Other things that can turn on the brake warning light:

Brake fluid level, check the level.
Brake proportional valve usually set off by a leaking brake line.

Comment: Hmm I didn't know that about the ebrake light.  Is it possible that the stuff on my hands was brake fluid?

Comment: @leeand00 doubtful the ebrake is a cable that runs to the brakes, no fluid involved.